# WebSocket connection failure

Tags: javascript, php, html, websocket

I downloaded this WebSocket example from this article:

- [Start Using HTML5 WebSockets Today | Nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/)

I did everything correctly as it says but I got some error like "only variables can pass…"

I changed this line:

```
$num_sockets = socket_select($changed_sockets,$write=NULL,$exceptions=NULL,NULL);
```

…to this:

```
$write=NULL;
$exceptions=NULL;
$num_sockets = socket_select($changed_sockets,$write,$exceptions,0);
```

…and the error is gone, but now it just connects then disconnects like this and does nothing:

```
2014-01-04 17:02:39 WebSocket: Resource id #9 CONNECTED!
2014-01-04 17:02:39 WebSocket: Requesting handshake...
2014-01-04 17:02:39 WebSocket: Handshaking...
2014-01-04 17:02:39 WebSocket: Done handshaking...
2014-01-04 17:02:39 WebSocket: Resource id #9 disconnected!
```

Comment: tried to change the last argument back to NULL?

Comment: @bbuecherl still nothing! :(

Comment: on which operating system you are doing the test?
In any case, you have to ensure that no firewall or antivirus is active, otherwise the ports used by the socket will be closed, and the service fails.

Comment: Try checking the option "Use secure WebSocket (TLS)". Hope it helps ..:)

Comment: and where is that? ;)